# EditText in RecyclerView only focused if scrolled to the top

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I've read dozens of posts of RecyclerView + EditText focus issues, but haven't found any about this particular problem.

I have a RecyclerView where the item layout contains a CardView, which in turn contains a LinearLayout with a few items inside. One of them is an EditText with some styling. (Actually, it's a custom view containing an EditText, but the issue appears with a plain EditText as well.)

By default, the EditText is disabled, and styled like a TextView. The user can then toggle "edit mode", which causes the EditText in each row to become enabled and editable.

When the RecyclerView is scrolled to the absolute top, the top EditText is automatically focused when you enable them, and you can start typing immediately.
However, when it's not scrolled to the top, *no* EditText is focused, and I've been unable to focus one programmatically as well (e.g. by calling requestFocus on the appropriate EditText).

Here's some minimal sample code that shows this behavior:

MainActivity.kt:

```
package org.exscape.recyclerviewfocusissue

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.Menu
import android.view.MenuItem
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val adapter = MyAdapter()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        recyclerView.adapter = adapter
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu)
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem?): Boolean = when (item?.itemId) {
        R.id.toggle -> { adapter.toggle(); true }
        else -> super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
}
```

MyAdapter.kt:

```
package org.exscape.recyclerviewfocusissue

import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.EditText
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

class MyAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {
    private val contents = (1..100).toList()
    private var enabled = false

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = contents.size

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false)

        return ViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        (holder as ViewHolder).editText.setText(contents[position].toString())
        holder.editText.isEnabled = enabled
    }

    fun toggle() {
        enabled = !enabled
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val editText : EditText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.editText)
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:id="@+id/editText"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

menu_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item android:id="@+id/toggle" android:title="Toggle" app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
</menu>
```

How can I solve this issue?
Ideally, the solution should focus the topmost fully visible (or partially visible, if it scrolls up) EditText on toggle, while also giving the ability for me to explicitly focus one of my choosing at any time.

**Update:** I got the example program to work by using `.post()` on the RecyclerView, and calling `requestFocus()` inside that Runnable, instead of immediately inside my `toggle()` method. I then switched to my custom view, and it still worked. However, my original program still doesn't work.
There is far too much code to post in the original, though. I will try to narrow the issue down further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, but it doesn't feel ideal. If anyone has a better solution, I'm absolutely open to changing my selected answer.

This can be fixed by calling `.post()` on the RecyclerView, and set focus manually in there. I'm not certain if there is a race condition, but if so I haven't hit it yet.

MyAdapter.kt:

```
package org.exscape.recyclerviewfocusissue

import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.EditText
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

class MyAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {
    private val contents = (1..100).toList()
    private var enabled = false
    private lateinit var attachedRecyclerView: RecyclerView

    override fun onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView: RecyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView)
        attachedRecyclerView = recyclerView
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = contents.size

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false)

        return ViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        (holder as ViewHolder).editText.setText(contents[position].toString())
        holder.editText.isEnabled = enabled
    }

    fun toggle() {
        enabled = !enabled
        notifyDataSetChanged()

        attachedRecyclerView.post {
            val layoutManager = attachedRecyclerView.layoutManager as? LinearLayoutManager
            if (layoutManager != null) {
                val position = layoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()
                if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION)
                    attachedRecyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(position)?.itemView?.requestFocus()
            }
        }
    }

    inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val editText : EditText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.editText)
    }
}
```